# Monodevelop C# user input

Tags: c#, keyboard, user-input, monodevelop, text-based

Sorry if this is a dumb question (I just started doing this) but I am currently trying to make a simple text-based RPG game in C# on Monodevelop. I want it to be that if you press 'Q' a block of text opens, ending the game.

To give a little more context, the game is based around getting points by choosing correct dialogue options. The player can choose to end the game at any time (by pressing Q), but if they end the game without enough points they get the "You lost" spiel, and if they end the game with enough points they get the "you won" spiel.

How do I do this? Thank you!